# Dropdown list that shows or hides a certain amount of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to make a dropdownlist where people can show and hide a number of divs within a form. I'm trying to make a questionnaire where people can create questions.

I've researched this but haven't found the results that I'm looking for. How do I make it, using Javascript, a function that can show and hide multiple divs?

For example, since theres five div tags. If i choose the number three on the option box, it should show three divs and hide two.

**The form**

```
Choose amount of questions: <select name="question"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select>

        <div name="section1">

        Subject: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
         Question: <input type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="video">
        </div>

        <br>
        <div name="section2">

        Subject: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
        Question: <input type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="video">

        </div>
        <br>
        <div name="section3">

        Subject: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
        Question: <input type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="video">

        </div>
        <br>

        <div name="section4">

        Subject: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
        Question: <input type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="video">

        </div>

    <br>
     <div name="section5">

        Subject: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
        Question: <input type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="video">
        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you also post what you have for javascript?

Comment: I haven't been able to make one that suits my needs. I made one that shows and hides two divs, but thats it. Should I post that one?@MannfromReno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$().ready(function()
{
  $('div[name^=section]').hide(); // hide all the div elements where name attribute starts with 'section' - NEEDED FOR HIDING ALL DIV'S DURING PAGE LOAD.
  $('select[name=question]').on("change",function() // delegate an onchange method to select element with name attribute = question.
  {
    $('div[name^=section]').hide(); // hide all the div elements where name attribute starts with 'section'
    var count = $(this).val(); // get the no. of questions to show as the value selected from the dropdown.
    for(var i=1; i <= count; i++)    // iterate through each element starts from 1 to count and show it.
       $('div[name^=section' + i + ']').show();
  });
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/3hvvdht9/4/

Comment: This still only shows 1 div you need to do something where if the div section is less than or equal to.

Comment: you have to use for loop before your hide

Comment: Actually hiding all items priority to show works better :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using bootstrap?  Look at the collapse example 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Also a little more clarification would help.